# conditional asc or desc in in a order byexpression

Tags: sql

I want to : if a is not null then order by a in ascending order, else order by b in descending order, so i write:

```
  select a, b from table order by ifnull(a asc, b desc);
```

But MySQL complains about syntax error

Any suggestions?

Comment: Sorry to say this makes no sense. Say your a/b pairs are 1/2, 3/1, NULL/2. Then where is NULL/2 supposed to be? Your order is a=1, a=3 so far (ascending) and then you want to insert b=2 descendingly? You certainly mean something else. For example order by a asc and then by b desc, as snyder suggests. Please clarify your request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really don't need an IF statement here.  If column "a" is null, then it would have no affect on the way the results are ordered based on column "b".

```
SELECT a, b 
FROM table 
ORDER BY a asc, b desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just skip `ifnull` like this :

```
select a, b from test order by a asc, b desc
```

Here is the [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1bd65/3)

If you want to `order by` only when `a` is `NULL` value and leave the order as its when `a` is `NON NULL`, then you can do the following:

```
select a, b from test order by a asc, 
case when a IS NULL THEN b ELSE 0 END desc
```

Here is the [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d341a/2), you can see in this fiddle that the sql leaves the order as it is when `a` has `NON NULL` values, it only orders them when `a` has `NULL` values.